# Why is that the light is moving in this Webgl example

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, webgl2

Here is an example of Goraud interpolation and a Lambertian reflection model from a textbook.

https://jsfiddle.net/zhenghaohe/r73knp0h/6/

However in the textbook there is a stupid error, in this book it says the code should contain this following line, when in fact **it does not**.

`vec3 light = vec3(uModelViewMatrix * vec4(uLightDirection, 0.0));`

The weird thing is the example still seems to work.

I am aware of that the sphere is rotating because

`mat4.rotate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, angle * Math.PI / 180, [0, 1, 0]);`

 However it seems to me that **the light** is also moving with the sphere. But in the code I cannot find how the light is being moved around.

Can someone please point me to the code where we also rotate the light?

Comment: The sphere is being rotated: `mat4.rotate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, angle * Math.PI / 180, [0, 1, 0])`

Comment: yea I know the sphere is being rotated. But it seems to me  that the light is also rotating. Or the light is not actually rotating?

Comment: sorry man I don't understand what you mean by I also need to rotate the normals... My question is not "how can I rotate the light". Apparently the code I posted is rotating the light, I just don't know how it did it.

Comment: Light works based on surface normals (a normal is a vector perpendicular to a face), it uses the surface normal to compute how the light should look. When you rotate just the sphere, but not its normals the light appears to rotate, but really the normals are just pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. so you mean the code is rotating the surface, which also rotates the normals. That is the reason why the light appears to be rotating as well. Therefore if I **only** want to rotate the sphere not the light, I need to stop the normals from rotating?

Comment: I'm saying that when you rotate an object you have to also rotate the normals the same way for light to work correctly. If you were actually moving the light around, but not the sphere you would not need to do anything to the normals.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by saying "when you rotate an object you have to also rotate the normals the same way for light to work **correctly**" , specifically, how do you define the light is working  **correctly**? I am not clear on how we can separate the rotation of the light and the sphere. Sure I know the light is computed based on the normals, which is the direction of the surface. But when I rotate the sphere, are the normals naturally rotating along with the sphere? Is this the reason that the code I posted doesn't explicitly change the `lightDirection` but the light is rotating?

Comment: you might find [this article helpful](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-directional.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The light does not rotate, it is fixed in a static position and direction. The problem here is you do not seem to understand what a normal is and how it is used in computer graphics.

A computer model is a series of "vertices" that connect to form "faces" (usually triangles). When "realistic" light is introduced into a scene an additional piece of information is necessary to determine how it should interact with each face of the model, this is called a "normal." A normal is a directional vector that generally forms a line perpendicular to a face, but it does not have to which will become important for your problem. This normal is used to compute how light interacts with that surface.

So you have three sets of data: The vertices, the indicies (how the verticies come together to form faces), and the normals (computed automatically in your example). The problem arises when you begin to make transformations to the model (like rotation) but do not perform similar transformations to the normals that were computed before the transformation.

Let's visualize this... say we have the following pyramid with one of it's normals drawn to illustrate the problem:

[image: Figure A]

Now when we start to rotate the pyramid, but we leave the normals directions unchanged we see that the angle between the normal and the face begins to change.

[image: Figure B]

[image: Figure C]

For things to work as expected we need to also rotate the normals so that the angle relative to the face does not change.

[image: Figure D]

The angle of the light relative to the surface normal is what dictates how the surface is shaded by the light. When you're rotating the model the normals begin pointing in "random" directions, this messes with the light computation and it appears as if the light is rotating, but it is not.

Obviously this is a very watered down explanation of what is happening, but it should give you a basic understanding of what a normal is and why you need to apply transformations to them as well.